# How to change Icon for Document Library in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, image-display

On my sharepoint online, team sites are already created.

I want to change the Icons of Document library to new images. i am trying to use many methods but could not succeed. As per microsoft, this is customised link may be made in Sharepoint designer, which is out of their support boundary.

so guys, can you help me out related to my issue.[image]

Comment: How you have set these icons previously?

Comment: Those are promoted links, and that's a list template. Use one of those.

Comment: @Kunal - will you accept/upvote Saber's answer please? This would be of benefit to other users too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **REST API**, **JSOM** or **CSOM**. I am not sure about from **UI** and **SharePoint Designer**. Have look on my **REST API** example.

- Upload your image in some Library.
- Add `l` prefix to image/icon name. For example, your image/icon name is `my-doc-icon.png`. Then after uploading to a library, change the name as `lmy-doc-icon.png`. **This is required**. Otherwise it does not work.

Now update your **Document library**.

## End point

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('library name')
```

## Request Body

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.List"
  },
  "ImageUrl": "relative url of your site/lmy-doc-icon.png"
}
```

You can use my [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to make this update request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Atish.. previous answer by Saber worked for me. but still thanks for your valuable responce

Comment: @Kunal - will you accept/upvote Saber's answer please?  This would be of benefit to other users too :)

Answer (score 0):

1- Download that wsp and rename to zip and extract and edit if you have scripting knowledge.

2- [Promoted Links](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/86a04dbe-6365-4e43-ad1b-c3ea7e2778f5/question-about-get-started-with-your-web-site-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneral) app is a new feature introduced in SharePoint 2013.

Add or Customize Tile Web Part this [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e02w17EfDRQ)

The [Get started](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/promoted-links-app-in-sharepoint-2013/) with your site web part is a new web part available with SharePoint server 2013.

[image: Add or Customize Tile Web Part this]